# Azure B2C Reset policy (forgotten password) - reset screen when unauthorised user tries to access page that requires authorisation

Tags: azure, reset, azure-ad-b2c, policy, forgot-password

I will add more details later when i have access to my laptop. But in essence, problem i am having wirh my mvc site that uses Azure b2c AD is as follows.

I have set up a sign-in-sign up policy, and a reset policy. Its a pretty standard set up as found on microsofts wiki pages. The reset policy works great when a user clickd on the forgotten password link found in the sign in template that comes out of the box. The issue is.....if a user is logged out and tries to access a protected resource (ie one with authorise attribute on it) the user gets redirected to password reset screen instead of the sign in screen (in other words....the reset policy is being triggered, even though tbe user has not clickef on forgotten password. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Could you add your authentication configuration code? I'm guessing it's using a default authentication scheme, which is setup to be the password reset policy.

Comment: Yes....i will add that later when i have access to my computer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to get it working.

In the end all I had to do was swap around the order in which I declared the policies.

The below snippet, resulted in the incorrect behaviour I described in my question.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager() });
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpSignInPolicyId));
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ResetPolicyId));   
}
```

Whilst, swapping the last two lines around so that the SignUpSignInPolicy appeared last, works a treat!

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager() });
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ResetPolicyId));
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpSignInPolicyId));
```

}